# How to reuse parameter estimates from Logistic model

Tags: sas, regression, logistic-regression, enterprise-guide

I try to use `PROC LOGISTIC` to compute regression parameter estimates for the `DATA1` data.
And I want to use `PROC SCORE` to score the `DATA2` data set by using the parameter estimates in the `DATA1` data set.

I know that it should work with `PROC REG`, but I have a Logistic Regression.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the CODE statement which generates the scoring code.

```
proc logistic data=sashelp.Bmt;
class Group;
model Status=Group;
code file='mycode.sas';
run;
```

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/65328/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_introcom_sect013.htm

EDIT: Within Logistic regression there's also a SCORE statement.